# Why do I get a Duplicate Key Error for auto-incremented ID's that don't exist?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

i have a table structured like so

```
 CREATE TABLE `person` (
   `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
   `pwd` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   `is_active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
   `source` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `language_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `create_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `modified_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `lastaccess_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `image_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `person_idx_1` (`email`),
 KEY `person_fk_1` (`source`),
 KEY `person_fk_2_idx` (`image_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `person_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`source`) 
   REFERENCES `person_source` (`uid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `person_fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) 
   REFERENCES `image` (`uid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=200002 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

there used to be about 190000 records in this table. i just used a proc to delete (in reverse FK order) all users but 7 in this database to do some targeted testing. after the data trimming, i was unable to insert data into this table. I got the following error:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'XXXXX' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I was able to repair this by altering the auto increment for the table to 200000 (notice my `show create table` output was at 200002), which I knew would be after the last record prior to deleting the data.

I get why my fix worked, but my question is what happened? Why did the auto-increment error appear when the records no longer existed in the table? Also, why wasn't the auto-increment value still at the original, higher value?

Much thanks!

Comment: Maybe a probem with your unique key?

Comment: I bet this will help you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: optimize table looks appropriate; i was unfamiliar with such a command/use! because i'm using a VM and happened to create snapshots at the right points, i can roll back and test this. i'll report back in a bit